# Does multiple action assignment addition run synchronously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, synchronization, action

Does the actions run **synchronously** or **asynchronously** when using `+=` operator?

```
Action actions = () => Console.WriteLine("First Action");

actions += () => Console.WriteLine("Second Action");
actions += () => Console.WriteLine("Third Action");
actions += () => Console.WriteLine("Fourth Action");

actions();
```

This block of code prints:

```
First Action
Second Action
Third Action
Fourth Action
```

Comment: `+=` for actions works similary to the delegates - it creates a kind of "list", which will be run step by step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this actions will run synchronously, just do this:

```
Action actions = () => Console.WriteLine("First Action");

actions += () => Console.WriteLine("Second Action");
actions += () => {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Third Action")
                 };
actions += () => Console.WriteLine("Fourth Action");
actions();
```

And you can check a Thread waiting to write the last one

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is short and simple: actions run **synchronously**. Just like event handles, actions are executed sequentially, one after another, in the order they are assigned / subscribed.

As you could have noticed, the block has been printed with all the strings in sequence. If you define something like this:

```
Action actions = () => Console.WriteLine("2");
actions += () => Console.WriteLine("3");
actions += () => Console.WriteLine("1");
actions += () => Console.WriteLine("4");
```

You will always see `2 3 1 4` being printed, no matter what happens.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that when performing complex things, the action may run assynchronously, what have been proved wrong. :) Thank you!!

Comment: On a side note... it's fine to do this for internal purpose, as long as you have full control on who subscribes actions and when. Multithreading subscription of actions could lead to unexpected result. The same can be said if you let API consumers subscribe them.